# Regular expression for SSN that accept one extra character

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for something for Social Security Number which is in the form `"###-##-####"`. I need a way that the first character can also be allowed to type `"@"`

How do I add that? I need it for a masked text box mask.

Comment: So to clarify # is a number 0-9 and you want to allow what you said or `@##-###-####`?

Comment: Social Security Numbers have only 2 digits in the middle section, not 3

Comment: @gunr2171 for Canada it is three digits, for US two digits. Plus that's not even the main point of my question .

Comment: @ConfusedSleepyDeveloper, I assumed you meant US format. Please edit your post to include that info (it helps the output).

Comment: @Chris so sorry, I checked the requirements again, the FIRSTcharacter can be "&" but they can still continue typing digits for the REST of the SSN as usual.

Comment: @ConfusedSleepyDeveloper: Ironically I am now getting a bit confused. Perhaps you should include some test cases - a bunch that should be accepted and a bunch that won't be accepted. This will make it both easier to understand your requirements and to confirm they have been met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need is this (\d is any digit and \d is \d escaped for c# and @? means it will accept 0 or 1 @)

```
@?\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d\\d
```

Comment: Check the comment in response to mine on the OP. The `@` is the only thing allowed if they type that.

Comment: It also says "Bad Compile Constant Value"

Comment: my bad didn't see the C# tag, you need to escape the backslashes

Comment: Thanks, let me try it quickly now.

Comment: I highly recommend regex101.com for any regex activities. Its very nice for figuring out what you want

Comment: @gunr2171 has a very good answer for a different interpretation of your question. Not sure which was what you had in mind

Comment: I want this:  the FIRSTcharacter can be "&" but they can still continue typing digits for the REST of the SSN as usual

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex:

```
^(@|\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d)$
```

(Note: this is with the US format: `###-##-####`)

The `^` and `$` mean the "start" and "end" of the string, so that you can't match items in the middle of your text.

The `|` says "one or the other". So it will match a `@`, or the digits.

The following will match

```
123-45-6789
@
```

but this won't match

```
234-3333-14234
@123-45-6789
```

You can [take a demo here](http://regexr.com/39r1g).

Make sure when you type this into c# you use the correct character escaping:

```
string pattern = @"^(@|\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d)$";
```

Comment: Side note: you can also use `^(?:@|\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d)$` if you want to avoid the capture group.

Comment: I may be reading the question wrong, but it seems like the OP wants an optional @ before the SSN, not a @ or a SSN.  And based on the comments maybe an optional & as well?

Comment: @juharr There was a deleted OP comment that said "either a @ or the number". I'll try to update my answer for [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678715/regular-expression-for-ssn-that-accept-one-extra-character#comment41956863_26678715)

Comment: "&" was typo..just "&"

Comment: Ok, I'm not going to update my answer until you type in your question the _exact_ requirements.